# Starting Jetty from Restlet in OSGi

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, restlet, equinox

I'm using Restlet in OSGi (equinox). I keep encountering a `java.io.IOException: The thread blocked at the cyclic barrier has timed out.` exception with the default HTTP server and so am trying to use Jetty instead. From reading various forums and articles, it seems that the correct way to use Jetty is to simply add the appropriate JARs to the classpath and Restlet does the hard work. This doesn't appear to be working :(

My bundle activator's `start` method looks as follows:

```
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {

    List<ConnectorHelper<Server>> servers = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers();
    System.out.println("Server connectors - "+servers.size());
    for (ConnectorHelper<Server> connectorHelper : servers) {
        System.out.println("connector = "+connectorHelper.getClass());
    }

    component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

    final Application app = new MyApplication();

    component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(app);
    component.start();
}
```

Running this prints:

```
Server connectors - 2
connector = class org.restlet.engine.local.RiapServerHelper
connector = class org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper
```

So it hasn't detected Jetty, which makes me think that the org.restlet.ext.jetty plugin isn't on the classpath. However, within the same method I'm able to access the Jetty helper classes. I've tried programmatically starting Jetty:

```
    Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8184, new MyApplication());
    JettyServerHelper jetty = new HttpServerHelper(server); 
    jetty.start();
```

Which shows that Jetty is on the classpath, and starts Jetty fine, but when I make a request to http://localhost:8184, I get the following exception:

```
2015-01-28 13:44:57.182:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2015-01-28 13:44:57.217:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8184
Jan 28, 2015 1:45:13 PM org.restlet.Restlet handle
WARNING: Unable to start the Restlet
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionHelper.createServerSocketChannel(ServerConnectionHelper.java:158)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionHelper.start(ServerConnectionHelper.java:320)
at org.restlet.Server.start(Server.java:590)
at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:315)
at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:513)
at org.restlet.engine.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:72)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:152)
at org.restlet.ext.jetty.JettyServerHelper$WrappedServer.handle(JettyServerHelper.java:170)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Does anyone know what I've configured incorrectly?

Many thanks,
Jim

Edit: Included list of running bundles:

```
id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610
            Fragments=156, 157
2   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505
40  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.200.v20130514-1256
            Master=118
53  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.300.v20120523-2004
65  ACTIVE      javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030
95  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.300.v20130429-1813
97  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20130327-1442
101 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.100.v20130422-1538
118 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549
            Fragments=40
119 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20130513-1956
124 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.100.v20131218-1515
126 ACTIVE      javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400
127 ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
130 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20130326-1255
134 ACTIVE      javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201209060031
156 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.v20130327-1442
            Master=0
157 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook_1.0.401.v20130327-1442
            Master=0
160 ACTIVE      org.restlet.ext.ssl_2.1.4.v20130907-1635
161 ACTIVE      org.restlet.ext.jetty_2.1.4.v20130907-1635
162 ACTIVE      jsslutils_1.0.5
163 ACTIVE      org.restlet_1.0.0
165 ACTIVE      org.restlet.ext.servlet_2.1.4.v20130907-1635
166 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20130429-0953
167 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
169 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
170 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.14.v20131031
171 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.14.v20131031
172 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.14.v20131031
173 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.14.v20131031
174 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.14.v20131031
175 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.14.v20131031
176 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.14.v20131031
180 ACTIVE      osgi.restlet.jetty.test_1.0.0.qualifier
```

My bundle is osgi.restlet.jetty.test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a bit tricky regarding connector detection when using Restlet within an OSGi environment. In fact, you need to be sure that you start your Restlet server once the jetty connector was registered against Restlet engine. I see two approaches for that:

- Use the start level of your OSGi container to ensure that the bundle that starts the Restlet engine is started after the Restlet bundles (`org.restlet.ext.jetty` and `org.restlet`.
- Use an OSGi framework event to start the Restlet engine when all bundles are started. A sample of this approach is described below:

  ```
  public class ServerActivator implements BundleActivator {
      public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
          this.context.addFrameworkListener(new FrameworkListener() {
              public void frameworkEvent(FrameworkEvent event) {
                  if (event.getType() == FrameworkEvent.STARTED) {
                      Component component = new Component();
                      Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8080);
                      server.setName("Sample Server");
                      server.setNext(new SampleApplication());
                      component.getServers().add(server);
                      component.start();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry, thanks for your reply. I've tried your solution, but sadly it still doesn't work. I also printed out the list of registered servers within the frameworkEvent() method, and it still only finds the RiapServerHelper and the HttpServerHelper. Perhaps I have not configured things properly? I'll add the list of running bundles to the question

Comment: Ah, pasting the registered bundles helped :) Turns out I was using an old version of Restlet that we'd packaged up (org.restlet_1.0.0). Using the correct version (org.restlet_2.1.4.v20130907-1635), along with your frameworkEvent solution, seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the version 1.0.0 is a bit old ;-) Pleased to hear that it works now!

Comment: Heh, it wasn't actually v1 - we had packaged up all Restlet jars into a single jar (was v2.1). Updated to 2.3 now though. Thanks again!